# Stack Reminder - Remind Yourself About Posts

Tags: app, script

### About

Stack Reminder allows you to save questions/answers to a special list, each with their own custom flag to remind you why you wanted the reminder in the first place.

This tool is a great resource when you are browsing around Stack Exchange, but cannot contribute until later. This will let you mark anything you would like to come back to later.

But what is it for? Some common uses:

- Mark posts from new users who may not know how to use the `@` feature of comments
- Marking interesting posts to easily access later (Sort of like "Favorites", but accessible from any page any time)
- Marking Meta discussions to easily link to/access later

  - See feature "Site Filter" below.

*If you have more common uses to add to this list, please let me know!*

---

## Features

- Mark questions OR answers
- Custom note for any content that is marked
- Access list of marked content from any page in the network without refreshing the page
- Access your marked content from any device with userscript support

  - This service uses an API key, which you can use on as many devices as you wish
- Share your list with others by sharing your API key
- Search Bar: to allow you to search through all of your marked content by the title or note that you left
- Site Filter: By default only show content marked on the website you are currently visiting, with a dropdown to switch between sites or show "All"

  - For example, if you have some meta discussions marked, you can switch your view to only show content from the Meta site, which you can then easily search through and copy the link for/visit *without changing pages*
- Purge all marked content, this will delete all content you have marked from your list
- Suggestion Sender: Send suggestions to the development team straight from the UI

---

### Download

Stack Reminder hooks your reminder list into my API service, which will allow you to access your list from any computer, or even share your list with other people.

First, you'll need a user script manager, such as [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/).

You'll need to generate a free API key [on the Stack Reminder backend](https://stack-remind.grumpycrouton.com/), then [install the userscript](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/raw/master/stack_reminder.user.js). Once the userscript is installed, it will pop up a prompt requesting your API key.

- (Note: If you are greeted with the prompt "A userscript wants to access a cross-origin resource.", Please click "Always Allow Domain")*

---

### Screenshots

This post has not been put on your reminder list, click "remind" to add it

[image]

---

When you add a post to your remind list, you will get this option to input a note about it

[image]

---

This post has been added to your reminder list, click "don't remind" to remove it

[image]

---

Easily see how many reminders are currently in your list

[image]

---

View your reminders list, with a search bar and options to filter by site. This interface is reachable from *any page in stack exchange that shows the sidebar*.

[image]

The "Site Selector" will default to only show posts from the site you are currently on in the network.

---

If you can think of any ways to make this better, let me know on GitHub or here in the comments.

This was written based on [a users suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378147/help-me-to-remember-and-get-back-to-posts-that-i-can-improve).

## UPDATES

- Aug 29) Fixed bug caused by change by SO.
- Jan 24) Reduced loudness of features on content that has not been interacted with yet. ("remind" button is not colored, until pressed)
- Jan 17) Most recent update changed some visuals, and added an "options" tab, where you can purge all of your marked posts and easily send ideas/suggestions.

Comment: This project has been put on the back-burner for me, partially due to less free time and partially due to the recent strike.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I found the exact error which I faced:

> cannot read property 0 or null

on this line when the script tries to attach custom DOM elements:

```
 site_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + value.site + '">Show Only ' + value.site[0].toUpperCase() + value.site.substr(1) + '</option>';
```

And fixed that to check null before this line:

```
if(value.site != null)
site_options += '<option ' + selected + ' value="' + value.site + '">Show Only ' + value.site[0].toUpperCase() + value.site.substr(1) + '</option>';
```

Now it works.

Comment: As it turns out, this would have only been an error on the old version. This can no longer be null, I just wasn't storing the site name before. If you had old reminders set, it was trying to pull the site from the database but it was literally null. Anyways, doesn't hurt to check it first! :)

Comment: Coult you pleae add `[tag:status-completed]` to the top of your question?

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can the button please *not* have the `color: red;` style?  The red button is pretty distracting for a feature I only use occasionally, and all of buttons of the other userscripts I use look identical to the existing share, edit, and flag buttons.

I don't mind adding some sort of styling after I've already set a reminder, but I'd prefer for the feature to not to stand out so loudly until I interact with it.

Comment: So you mean you want the text where it says "remind me" to be the same styling as the other buttons, but when a reminder is set, and the text is "don't remind me", it should still be colored? Or do you have some other styling in mind?

Comment: I was also thinking about changing the wording of these buttons to be a single word instead of multiple words, because all the other ones there are single words. "remember" and "forget" was the best that I could think of. What do you think? In this case I would probably make "remember" the default color, and "forget" a slightly pink-gray, like `#d48585`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Exactly: I’d prefer for the button to blend in with the others, except when a reminder has already been set.  As for wording, I think shortening “remind me” to “remind” would be fine.

Comment: And then keep "don't remind me" the same? Or should the text be the same whether a reminder has been set or not, and just change the color?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Maybe change it to “don’t remind” and change the color?

Comment: My main reason for wanting to change it was to make it a single word, to make it consistent with the other buttons there - In your opinion, does this consistency matter?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I like the consistency when the button says “remind,” but I’m not sure that it’s a big deal after the button’s been clicked.  With the color change, it’ll be easy to tell where the text begins and ends, so I think using two words is alright.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Do you think that the color change should "pop" quite a bit? Or should it just be slightly different than the other buttons?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think some “pop” is appropriate, but how much I’ll leave up to what you think is best.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Recent change on UI break your UserScript. I dig little bit more on your code and found  `short-link` class to bind **remind me** button on UI. Recent change remove class `short-link` so why it's not worked.

So to fix the problem you must change below code inside `function process_page(posts)`.

Replace:

```
$("a.short-link:contains('share')").each(function( index ) {
```

with:

```
 $("a.js-share-link").each(function( index ) {
```

Please update your repo.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

1. Button `Reminder List` and `Seetings` are not in there appropriate place.

[image: Image 1]

2. Show All Sites gives wrong result. I have 4 question on Reminder but `Show All Sites` option show only 3 result.

[image: App2]

Comment: Interesting... I'll try to figure this out. It doesn't look like this for me unless I zoom in to 150%

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can you change the Settings button color style to the blue from the "Post Your Answer" and a lot of more buttons always and just add a blue-ish border when clicking it?

Like most buttons that don't do dangerous stuff, it uses some sort of blue color and add a blue-ish border around it when clicking it.

Comment: For me, it already has the same style as the buttons on the page, it uses the default style of the stackexchange site you are currently on. Maybe I don't quite understand your request, do you think maybe you could add some screenshots of what you'd like it to look like?